# Moving mouse through multiple monitors on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

It is hard to explain so I have uploaded this image:

[image]

Can I move the mouse between monitors in "circles"? Let's say I want to move my mouse from A to A, B to B, C to C and in other directions too.

Comment: try using the term "Wrap-around" in your search. There are 3rd party utilities and monitor programs that do this, none of which I would know enough to recommend.  I do not believe this has ever been an available option in the windows 7 system or settings.